# FormData React, how to send data on two url endpoint

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem when sending input values ​​to the backend. I have 4 input fields (name, email, message and file), the first three are sent to one url and the files from the same form go to another url. How can I send through the same form with the axios.post method complete data from the form immediately on the submit button? I would use formData for that action

Comment: you can have two separate `POST` requests ....

Comment: Yes,i have two post request

Comment: so, what is the issue you are facing, also try to attach what you have tried so far, if any errors, details etc., ... which will help us help u

Comment: I would like to send it together as one request through formData, so that later on the backend, the get method would use the file to send emails, that is, to use the pdf from the input file for the download option in the email

Comment: Will this [help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_a_file) ?